# Assistance needed with join query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two very simple tables in Oracle 9G:

**Customer**

```
userid | firstName | lastName | email 
-------+-----------+----------+---------------------
  1      user1       User1      user1@mail.in
  2      user2       User2      user2@mail.in
```

**Order**

```
orderiD | userId | OrderType | Order_Date | Amount
--------+--------+-----------+------------+-------
1          1          0         12/12/2009    1
2          1          1         13/12/2009    2
3          1          1         14/12/2009    3
4          2          0         12/12/2009    4
5          2          1         16/12/2009    2
6          1          0         14/12/2009    5
7          2          1         17/12/2009    4
8          2          0         10/12/2010    2
```

I want to select all users which have orders of type 0

```
select *    
from Customer c 
inner join Order o on c.userid = o.userid 
where o.orderType = '0'
```

The result is:

```
orderiD | userId | OrderType | Order_Date | Amount
--------+--------+-----------+------------+--------
1          1          0         12/12/2009    1
4          2          0         12/12/2009    4
6          1          0         14/12/2009    5
8          2          0         10/12/2010    2
```

Now I need to modify this query to bring only last purchase date for each user id and get the result like this:

```
orderiD | userId | OrderType | Order_Date | Amount
--------+--------+-----------+------------+--------
6          1          0         14/12/2009    5
8          2          0         10/12/2010    2
```

How should I modify my query to get this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM order o
WHERE o.orderType ='0'
  AND o.order_date = 
      ( SELECT MAX(o2.order_date)
        FROM order o2
        WHERE o2.userid = o.userid
          AND o2.orderType = '0'
      )
```

or

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM order o
  JOIN
    ( SELECT userid
           , MAX(order_date) AS lastPurchaseDate
      FROM order 
      WHERE o.orderType ='0'
      GROUP BY userid
    ) AS grp
    ON grp.userid = o.userid
    AND grp.lastPurchaseDate = o.order_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * 
from   customer c
,      order o
where  c.userid = o.userid 
and    o.orderType ='0'
and    o.order_date = (
    select max(o2.order_date)
    from   order o2
    where  o2.userid = o.userid
)
```

Answer (score 0):

No subquery required, just aggregate functions.

```
select c.userId, o.OrderType, 
       max(o.Order_Date),  
       max(o.orderiD) keep (dense_rank last order by order_date),  
       max(o.Amount) keep (dense_rank last order by order_date)
from Customer c inner join Order o
on c.userid = o.userid where o.orderType ='0'
group by c.userId, o.OrderType
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Order o
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(o.id) AS maxid
FROM Customer c 
INNER JOIN Order o ON c.userid = o.userid 
WHERE o.orderType ='0'
GROUP BY c.userid) x ON x.maxid = o.id
```

Comment: How does that get the max date?

Comment: In some sense the solution is a cheat/shortcut because it assumes that the o.id will be ordered by date (which is likely to be true).  But you could imagine a scenario where the order_date is changed, in which case, this SQL would not be quite right.

Comment: This is wrong in so many ways. @danny: Please, add a row in order table with `9,  2,  0, 14/12/2009, 9` and run the query again to see why.